# как получить несколько кук

Tags: android, cookie

использовал вот эту страницу https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150089/how-to-handle-cookies-in-httpurlconnection-using-cookiemanager/16171708#16171708

но мне почему то приходит только 1 строка а у меня их 2 так же как в том примере вот мой код может я что то пишу неправильно

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "https://www.example.center/api/login";
        String login2 = "http://www.example2.win/index.php?action=login";
        if (type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String email = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                URL url2 = new URL(login2);
                final String COOKIES_HEADER = "Set-Cookie";
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection2 = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
                java.net.CookieManager msCookieManager = new java.net.CookieManager();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection2.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection2.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                OutputStream outputStream2 = httpURLConnection2.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                 + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter2 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream2, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data2 = URLEncoder.encode("myusername", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&"
                                 + URLEncoder.encode("mypassword", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter2.write(post_data2);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                bufferedWriter2.flush();
                bufferedWriter2.close();
                outputStream.close();
                outputStream2.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStream inputStream2 = httpURLConnection2.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
                BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream2, "UTF-8"));
                Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = httpURLConnection2.getHeaderFields();
                List<String> cookiesHeader = headerFields.get(COOKIES_HEADER);

                if (cookiesHeader != null) {
                    for ( String cookie : cookiesHeader) {
                        msCookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null, HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
                        cookies = cookie;
                    }

                }
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                bufferedReader2.close();
                inputStream.close();
                inputStream2.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                httpURLConnection2.disconnect();
                JSONObject obj= null;
                try {
                    obj = new JSONObject(result);
                    String status=obj.getString("status");
                    JSONObject data_obj=obj.getJSONObject("data");
                    win_user=data_obj.getString("id");
                    name=data_obj.getString("name");
                    logo=data_obj.getString("logo");

                    return win_user;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();}
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result == null ) {
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(context, "Email or Password is not match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            pass.show();
        }
        else
        {
            context.startActivity( new Intent(context,Main.class));
            Main.JSON_STRING = result;
            Main.name = name;
            Main.logo = logo;
            Main.win_user = win_user;
            Main.cookie = cookies;
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(context, cookies, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            pass.show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

вот так записаны куки

```
Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=....;path=/
Set-Cookie:usrnm......;expires.....;path=/;domain=www.example2.com
```

в тосте высвечивается только `Set-Cookie:PHPSESSID=....;path=/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одна из самых трудно уловимых ошибок - это когда просто плюсик пропустил ;)

```
    for (String cookie : cookiesHeader) {
        msCookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null, HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
        cookies += cookie; // смотреть сюда
    }
```

Comment: спасибо большое но все же у меня не выходит Set-Cookie:usrnm......;expires.....;path=/;domain=www.example2.com так как она должна выходить после ввода логина и пароля, проверьте пожалуйста правильно ли я отправляю логин и пароль @woesss

Comment: и пожалуйста можете посмотреть вот этот вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643532/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-cookie-%D0%B2-web-socket

Comment: @Sergey Вы стучитесь по двум адресам, а куки берёте с одного - может в этом причина? Просто по коду непонятно что откуда должно прийти и для чего вообще Вам нужно куки вручную выковыривать.

Comment: так и нужно, но куки я уже получил теперь как его отправить случайно не подскажите?